# Python-AWS Cloudwatch-get RDS instance name

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm totally noob for Python, i found this on GitHub and it works as expected, but couldn't figure out how to edit this to add RDS name/Lambda function name/ to output.

So don't know metric if more than one RDS/Lambda/ELB/Application ELB are monitored by zabbix.

https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch/blob/master/zabbixCloudWatch.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after line 191 try:

```
elif aws_service == 'service name':
               topic_name = dimensions['FunctionName']
               zabbix_key =  aws_service + '.' + metric_name + '.' + statistics + '["' + account + '","' + aws_region + '","' + topic_name + '"]'
```

make sure that Zabbix key reflects code above

Comment: this seems to be working, now need to figure out how to put service name into triggers, thanks !